# Nested for-loop in idiomatic JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm translating some code from Python to JavaScript and I need to rewrite the following nested for-loop list comprehension (where `solution` is a dictionary of string keys and list values).

```python
events = [e for key in solution.keys() for c in solution[key] for e in c.events]
```

Without giving it much thought, I'd translate it to something like this unwieldy, ugly nested for-loop.

```js
const events = []

for (const key of solution.keys()) {
    for (const c of solution[key]) {
        for (const e of c.events) {
            events.push(e)
        }
    }
}
```

But maybe there's a nicer way. How can I rewrite the above nested for-loop in short, idiomatic, modern (ES2015+) JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s not a much nicer way. The original Python should be using `values`:

```python
events = [e for foo in solution.values() for c in foo for e in c.events]
```

which you can reflect in JavaScript:

```js
const events = [];

for (const foo of solution.values()) {
    for (const c of foo) {
        for (const e of c.events) {
            events.push(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty short and easy to read (or it will be when `foo` is replaced with an appropriate name). You can use `concat` if you like creating lots of intermediate lists:

```js
const events = [];

for (const foo of solution.values()) {
    for (const c of foo) {
        events = events.concat(c.events);
    }
}
```

and `reduce` if you like function calls that don’t really save space or readability, assuming the values of `solution` are arrays:

```js
const events = [];

for (const foo of solution.values()) {
    events = foo.reduce(
        (m, n) => m.concat(n.events),
        events
    );
}
```

and `Array.from` and `reduce` if you really like intermediate lists and don’t really like readability:

```js
const events =
    Array.from(solution.values()).reduce(
        (events, foo) => events.concat(
            foo.reduce(
                (m, n) => m.concat(n.events),
                events
            )
        ),
        []
    );
```

Defining more functions dulls the pain but doesn’t change the fact that ES6 is not so great

```js
const concat = arrays =>
    arrays.reduce((m, n) => m.concat(n), []);

const concatMap = (fn, arrays) =>
    concat(arrays.map(fn));

const events = concatMap(
    foo => concatMap(foo, c => c.events),
    Array.from(solution.values())
);
```

Maybe the standard library is missing some iterator functions

```js
function* map(fn, iterable) {
    for (const x of iterable) {
        yield fn(x);
    }
}

function* concat(iterables) {
    for (const iterable of iterables) {
        yield* iterable;
    }
}

const concatMap = (fn, iterables) =>
    concat(map(fn, iterables));

const events = Array.from(
    concatMap(
        ([key, foo]) => concatMap(c => c.events, foo),
        solution
    )
);
```

Stick with the for loops, honestly.

Comment: Very thorough, enlightening answer. Thank you!